# Is nefness preserved under base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, descent

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between (geometrically normal) varieties over a field $k$, $\bar{k}$ be the algebraic closure of $k$ and $B$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$ which is $f$-nef, that is if $C$ is a curve on $X$ contracted to a point by $f$,  $$D \cdot C \geqslant 0$$

Is the corresponding Cartier divisor $\overline{B}$ on $\overline{X}$ is still $f$-nef ?

The question more generally is : how do the different cones $\overline{NE}$, $Mov$, etc. and the spaces $N^1$ and $N_1$ behave under base change ?

Comment: I think the answer to the first question is trivially yes: a reduced curve $\bar C\subseteq \bar X$ contracted by $\bar f$ is defined over a finite Galois extension $k'/k$, and then the curve $C' = \sum_{{\rm Gal}(k'/k)} g\cdot \bar C$ is defined over $k$ and contracted by $f$. Thus $D\cdot C' \geq 0$, but $D \cdot C' = [k':k] \cdot (\bar D \cdot \bar C)$, so $\bar D\cdot \bar C \geq 0$.

Comment: Hi ! Did you assume that $k$ is perfect here ? (It's ok because I want to apply it to finite fields).